# Problem with thmtools: thmbox and numbered=no

Tags: theorems, thmtools

I've got a problem when I try to use the options `thmbox=M` and `numbered=no` at the same time in the `thmtools` package. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[numbered=no, name=TheoremA,         ]{mytheo1}
\declaretheorem[             name=TheoremB, thmbox=M]{mytheo2}
%\declaretheorem[numbered=no, name=TheoremC, thmbox=M]{mytheo3} -> Here the error accurs

\begin{document}

\begin{mytheo1}
    test1
\end{mytheo1}

\begin{mytheo2}
    test2
\end{mytheo2}

\end{document}
```

The Styles 1 and 2 work great, but uncommenting the third `\declaretheorem...` line will produce the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
! LaTeX Error: \mytheo3 undefined
```

Does anybody know, if there's a way to use both, `thmbox` and `nonumbered` option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the `thmbox` option is used, the control is passed to the `thmbox` package, which doesn't provide unnumbered theorems.

This means that you cannot use that option together with `numbered=no` option.

As a workaround, to obtain the theorem environment you were looking for, define

```
\newenvironment{mytheo3}{%
  \thmbox[M]{\textbf{TheoremC}}%
  \hspace*{-1.5em}\slshape\ignorespaces%
  }
  {%
  \endthmbox\vspace*{.75ex}%
  }
```

to be used like

```
\begin{mytheo3}
    test3
\end{mytheo3}
```

or

```
\newenvironment{mytheo4}[2][M]{%
  \thmbox[#1]{\textbf{#2}}%
  \hspace*{-1.5em}\slshape\ignorespaces%
  }
  {%
  \endthmbox\vspace*{.75ex}%
  }
```

to be used like

```
\begin{mytheo4}[M]{TheoremD}
    test4
\end{mytheo4}
```

Since in this case `M` is the default, it can be omitted.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[numbered=no, name=TheoremA,         ]{mytheo1}
\declaretheorem[             name=TheoremB, thmbox=M]{mytheo2}
%\declaretheorem[numbered=no, name=TheoremC, thmbox=M]{mytheo3} % this doesn't work!!!!!!!!!!

\newenvironment{mytheo3}{%
  \thmbox[M]{\textbf{TheoremC}}%
  \hspace*{-1.5em}\slshape\ignorespaces%
  }
  {%
  \endthmbox\vspace*{.75ex}%
  }

\newenvironment{mytheo4}[2][M]{%
  \thmbox[#1]{\textbf{#2}}%
  \hspace*{-1.5em}\slshape\ignorespaces%
  }
  {%
  \endthmbox\vspace*{.75ex}%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{mytheo1}
    test1
\end{mytheo1}

\begin{mytheo2}
    test2
\end{mytheo2} 

\begin{mytheo3}
    test3
\end{mytheo3}

\begin{mytheo4}[M]{TheoremD}
    test4
\end{mytheo4}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. When `thmbox` is used, control is passed to the `thmbox` package, which doesn't provide unnumbered theorems.

Comment: @egreg And why does it not compile?

Comment: Is it a bug of your bicycle if you can't go with it across the sea?

Comment: @egreg Got it. Answer edited...

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wandering here after all these years, and who does not like to have any numbered theorem, I just found out that adding

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thmbox@headstyle[2]{\bfseries #1}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble will disable ALL of the numberings made by `thmbox` (default values being: `\bfseries\boldmath#1 #2`, as stated in [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/thmbox/thmbox.pdf)).